# How To Retrieve Data API Web Script Using PHP With Authentication Login User and Password?

Tags: java, php, api

Help, I never did this before. I am so confused.
How to get and echo the data from API web script, but it required user login.

The link looks like `http://[my_url]/alfresco/s/api/workflow-instances`

Here is the data from API Web script :

```
{ "data": [{
   "id": "activiti$162149",
   "url": "api\/workflow-instances\/activiti$162149",
   "name": "activiti$cwfpm4",
   "title": "004 SO Broadcast",
   "description": "Gate 4 dari Sistem Manajemen Dokumentasi Proyek",
   "isActive": true,
   "startDate": "2017-01-11T19:31:07.000+07:00",
   "priority": 2,
   "message": "P18M0002 - Project Management Workflow",
   "endDate": null,
   "dueDate": null,
   "context": "workspace:\/\/SpacesStore\/fe2896bc-adfe-48f7-b990-9308e327ff7e",
   "package": "workspace:\/\/SpacesStore\/ab114d0a-f370-4e20-92ee-f22c3e09d87f",
   "initiator": 
   {
      "userName": "U_MAS",
      "firstName": "U_MAS",
      "lastName": ""
   },
   "definitionUrl": "api\/workflow-definitions\/activiti$cwfpm4:70:161630"}
]}
```

I've tried the following:

```
$json_string = file_get_contents("[my_url]/alfresco/s/api/workflow-instances?alf_ticket=''");
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
```

Here's the ticket autentication using java:

```
    public String generateTicketSource() throws JSONException {
            String alfrescoTiccketURL = alfrescoUrl + "/alfresco"+"/service/api/login?u="+userName+ "&pw="+password;
            String ticketURLResponse = invokeWebScriptgetRequest(alfrescoTiccketURL);
            return ticketURLResponse;
        }
 public static String invokeWebScriptgetRequest(String url) {
            String ticket = null;
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            GetMethod method = new GetMethod(url);
            String response = null;
            try {
                int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);
                if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                    System.err.println("Method failed: " + method.getStatusLine());
                }
                byte[] responseBody = method.getResponseBody();
                response = new String(responseBody);
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                ticket = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data").getString("ticket");
            } catch (HttpException e) {
                System.err.println("Fatal protocol violation: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Fatal transport error: " + e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                method.releaseConnection();
            }
            return ticket;
        }
```

The ticket variable on java will use for authentication login that follows the

```
link -> [url]?alf_ticket=tiket (on file_get_contents)
```

I've no idea on that, I want to echo the data from API web script.

Comment: Do not vandalize questions that have been answered. The purpose of this site is to help others. Just because it's solved for you doesn't mean the question is not useful. If a question is only useful to one person, then it generally doesn't belong here anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what solved it:

```
$url = '[my_url]';

$username = 'user';
$password = 'password';

$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")
    )
));
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

echo $data;
```